# Issues with Classic ASP on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, asp

The project I'm working on is currently using classic ASP running under IIS7.  We are considering migrating to ASP.NET for portions of the code, but would still likely have some classic ASPs around still.

It is my understanding that our ASP.NET code will likely run better on IIS7, but are there any issues or gotchas to be aware of with running classic ASP under IIS7?

Any insight, tips, or advice would be valuable!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article will suffice.  http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth - all of our production servers run Server 2003/IIS 6, but all of our development machines are Vista/IIS 7 and our main applicatication is Classic ASP. It runs on both platforms without any issues. We're slowly migrating to .NET 3.5 - but both can co-exist without any problems.

Comment: Update: We're migrating our Server 2003/IIS6 VMs to Server 2008/IIS7 without any issues to date.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to IIS6 until you migrate everything over to ASP.Net. You'll find more people have that configuration and if you do have issues they will be easier to troubleshoot and find help for.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff that bit us were:

Minor: APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH no longer returns "\" with path - so anything that expected it 
broke

MAJOR: Session_OnEnd does not work

[This post](http://blogs.iis.net/lprete/archive/2009/01/04/session-onend-classic-asp-and-iis-7-0.aspx) shows you how to fix it but this drove us nuts for about 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 would really be the way to go if it were me. The only real trouble is that Classic ASP and ASP.NET do not share the same session. So if you're making use of InProc session state you will need to do some work-arounds in the code.

I would also read the article that jinsungy posted, it has some very good tips.